# Save form data to XML using PHP with overwrite feature

Tags: php, html, xml

I'm trying to make form data save in an exertnal XML file.
The XML file already exists and is already populated with some data.

I need to save the form data to the XML file but it needs to add new record everytime EXCEPT if the  section in the XML file is the same as the new form submission. If that happens, it needs to modify the record in the XML file that had the same  data.

So if someones names Mario Bros and fills the form for the first time, it would create a new record in the XML file. If that same Mario Bros re-fill the form with the same name, but different "Location" in the form, it will overwrite the already existing Mario Bros in the XML file.

Here's my HTML code :

```
<form>
<table width="50%" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td> First name:</td><td> <input type="text" name="firstname"></td>
    <td> Last name:</td><td>  <input type="text" name="lastname"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> Location:</td><td> <input type="text" name="location"></td>
    <td> Report:</td><td> <select name="report">
                             <option value="Wind Damage" selected>Wind Damage</option>
                             <option value="Hail">Hail</option>
                             <option value="Flooding">Flooding</option>
                             <option value="Power Outage">Power Outage</option>
                             <option value="General">General</option>
                          </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td> Description: </td><td colspan="4"> <textarea rows="5" cols="65" name="desc" onfocus="this.value=''">Enter report description</textarea></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td colspan="4" style="text-align:center;"><input type="submit" name="lsr-submit" value="Submit"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Here's my PHP code

```
<?php

$str = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><entrys></entrys>';
$xml = simplexml_load_string($str);

$fname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lname = $_POST['lastname'];
$location = $_POST['location'];
$report = $_POST['report'];
$description = $_POST['desc'];

$fname = htmlentities($fname, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8', false);
$lname = htmlentities($lname, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8', false);
$location = htmlentities($location, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8', false);
$report = htmlentities($report, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8', false);
$description = htmlentities($description, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8', false);

$xml->reports = "";
$xml->reports->addChild('fname', $fname);
$xml->reports->addChild('lname', $lname);
$xml->reports->addChild('location', $location);
$xml->reports->addChild('report', $report);
$xml->reports->addChild('description', $description);

$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$doc->formatOutput = true;
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = true;
$doc->loadXML($xml->asXML(), LIBXML_NOBLANKS);
$doc->save('test2.xml');

?>
```

What am I doing wrong? I can't seem to find a way to make it work. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Where you read previous data from the file? Where you check add data or update?

Comment: That's what I don't know how to do (to add or update data). Right now it always replace the data, and does not create multiple records in the XML. So it always replace the only record in the XML file

Comment: maybe someone write the code for you, maybe not...

Comment: What do you mean? I don't want someone to necessarily write the code for me, I need help...

Comment: Ok 1st) read doc om simplexml how read xml from file. 2nd) how write to file.... So, read the doc before. Now there isn't a question

Answer (score -1):

$file = fopen("data.xml","a");

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).